# GCC Compiler Conflicting Types For Function Definition And Implementation Even Though They Have The Same Type

Tags: c

i wanted to port a project of mine from Visual Studio 2019 to GCC.
Unfortunately the compiler complains about conflicting types for a function declaration and implementation when they literally are the same.

**entity.h** :

```
#pragma once

void MicroEntitySetInit(struct MicroEntity* entity, void (*init)(struct MicroEntity* self, struct MicroApplication* app));

void MicroEntitySetUpdate(struct MicroEntity* entity, void (*update)(struct MicroEntity* self, struct MicroApplication* app, float delta));
```

**entity.c** :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "../entity.h"
#include "../application.h"

void MicroEntitySetInit(
        struct MicroEntity* entity,
    void (*init)(struct MicroEntity* self, struct MicroApplication* app)) {
    entity->functions->init = init;
}

void MicroEntitySetUpdate(
    struct MicroEntity* entity,
    void (*update)(struct MicroEntity* self, struct MicroApplication* app, float delta)) {
    entity->functions->update = update;
}
```

**Error** :

```
./Engine/Core/Implementation/entity.c:85:6: error: conflicting types for 'MicroEntitySetInit'; have 'void(struct MicroEntity *, void (*)(struct MicroEntity *, struct MicroApplication *))'
   85 | void MicroEntitySetInit(
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ./Engine/Core/Implementation/entity.c:4:
./Engine/Core/Implementation/../entity.h:32:6: note: previous declaration of 'MicroEntitySetInit' with type 'void(struct MicroEntity *, void (*)(struct MicroEntity *, struct MicroApplication *))'
   32 | void MicroEntitySetInit(struct MicroEntity* entity, void (*init)(struct MicroEntity* self, struct MicroApplication* app));
```

The MSVC Compiler Doesn't Throw Any Errors nor Warnings. But The GCC Compiler Can't Compile At This Exact Part.
I Searched For Similar Problems But Had No Luck.
Any Help Would Be Appreciated.